# Prevent users from re-clicking "Like" button on page refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I want to stop a user from clicking a *Like* button multiple times.  I can disable the button on the first click using jQuery, but when the page is refreshed, the user can again click the button.  How do I prevent a user from re-clicking the button on page refresh?

Answer (score 3):

you can store the user id in database who have already liked and disable the like button/link for them so they once click on the button or link never click again

Comment: I dont have user id any global user can like .I can stop using ip but i can also use cookies or session but i am scare to use too much session object create. i have a more then 10K records each record have like please tell me which option is best cookies or session.

Comment: you can use html5 Session it you have knowledge and] this and both are good in that case

Answer (score 0):

use js to block the UI

like so: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

google "js block ui"

sorry for the short answer

edit: did not read your question properly i guess,   see Mayank swami's post , he has your answer

Comment: I have more then 10K records each record have like option how i handle like option using session or cookies because user cant like again if he click once.

Comment: so u have 10 k "items" that can be "liked"   and u want each user to only like each item once ? but u have no way of identifying a user ...

Answer (score 0):

You should check it in Server side.
use can use $_SESSION for this purpose.
When user click on link set

```
$_SESSION['liked']=true;
```

and then check if user clicked before. Session won't be destroyed in when page refreshed.